# Can not update/insert/etc. Meteor.Collection from console

Tags: mongodb, google-chrome, meteor

The problem has came suddenly. I have Meteor.Collection X, I define it `X = new Meteor.Collection "x"`, when I restart meteor, all is ok, it insert anything I need on `meteor.startup`. But when i'd like to insert or update something from chrome JS console like this `X.update({name: "Name"}, {$set:{name: "NewName"}})` - it says, that `ReferenceError: X is not defined`. As I understand, it think, that X is variable, not a collection... It works earlier, but now it's not.

So have you got any idea, how can I operate my collection from console?

Comment: Where does "X" come from? Isn't your collection called Brokers?

Comment: sorry, my fault. I use X for non context explanation.

Comment: do you use coffeescript?

Comment: @Akshat yes, it matters? it has worked earlier, but I use coffeescript too..
If it helps, here my server code http://pastebin.com/TT2BXsHX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like X is defined on the server only. The statement `X = new Meteor.Collection "x"` has to be in a file that's executed on both the client and the server.

You can try putting a logging statement next to that line and see if it appears in your Chrome JS console.

Comment: Ok, thanks. X was defined on client, but it was defined w/o clear declaring it as global. Now, I make it `@X` and it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Meteor 0.6.0+, if you want to declare a global variable X, you must not use the **var** keyword. Otherwise the variable will be accessible from only the file in which it is declared.

Comment: I do not use `var`. More, I use `@X` at server to show it is global.